# Ionic: can't build Android app

Tags: android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an Android app using `inonic build android` but I have the following error:

```
running cordova build android
Running command: "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\xampp\htdocs\discipulado\
discipulado\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js c:/xampp/htdocs/discip
ulado/discipulado
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: c:\xampp\htdocs\discipulado\discipulado\platforms\android\cordo
va\build.bat
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-21".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Users\Thiago\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
\tools\android.BAT
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-21
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: c:\xampp\htdocs\discipulado\discipul
ado\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: c:\xampp\htdocs\discipulado\discipulado\platforms\android\cordova\build.b
at: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\Thiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I already installed Apache Ant, but the error remains. I removed the Android platform with `ionic platform remove android` and added with `ionic platform add android` with no success.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
I already installed Android Studio and Android SDK Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, your system needs to install "android-21", which is Android 5.0 Lollipop

Comment: I've checked the Android SDK Manager and the following items are installed **Android 5.0.1**: SDK Platform, Google APIs, Sources for Android SDK.

Comment: The thing you missed is, in the environmental variable PATH, add these two items 1. path-to-android-sdk-***/tools 2. path-to-android-sdk-***/platform-tools. Update me if it works.

Comment: Not sure what happened. I've just rewrite the `ant/bin` folder in the `Path` and it worked.